# What is the use of square brackets in writing lines to a new file (Python)

Tags: python, list, io, list-comprehension

```
with open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        [outfile.write(d + "\n") for d in data]
```

I don't understand the use of the square brackets in this statement. From my understanding, this will create a new list, and when I delete the square brackets, I get the error:

```
  File "test.py", line 6
    outfile.write(d + "\n") for d in data
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to understand the  "[]" in this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The grammar of a list comprehension (first code snippet) is just defined differently by Python from the grammar of an ordinary for-loop.

Comment: In this instance, the square brackets denote a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It is not illegal but I wouldn't use a list comprehension here because it seems to obscure rather than simplify the code.

Comment: @NicholasHunter So instead of creating a new list, it just does some operations on each item in the list, and in this case, outputs a new line. Can I understand in this way?

Comment: Yes, that's what it's doing. Normally one would use a list comprehension to create a list like so `results =  [outfile.write(d + "\n") for d in data]`. If you did that here, you would get a list of the return values of each call to outfile.write. Since outfile.write has no return value, I guess you would get a list of Nones.